# Testing if a string starts by a "C"

Tags: php

I'm using php. Can you please tell me how can I test if a string starts by a C and have exactly 4 characters?

Thanks

Comment: @vikky, he probably did and ended up here. IMHO this is a basic but legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is short way

```
if($string[0] == 'C' && strlen($string) == 4) return TRUE;
else return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (substr($string, 0, 1) == 'C' && strlen($string) == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos and strlen function to find it.

`if(strpos($string,'C')===0 && strlen($string)==4)`

Comment: This will not work, because if the string does not contain a "C" and is 4 characters long this will also evaluate to `true`. Use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

just grab the substring from the end to the beginning, 4 steps backwards , it must be 1 character that has to be a 'C'

```
substr($string, 0,-3) == 'C'
```